# convert integer to formated binary string in python2.6

Tags: python, type-conversion, string-formatting, python-2.6

In python2.7 `"{:010b}".format(25)` would return `'0000011001'` giving a 10 bit binary string representation of the number 25. In python2.6 the same command returns `ValueError: zero length field name in format`. Is there a different way doing simple formated conversions for python2.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`format()` function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#format), it's easier (no need for the template placeholder parts, only the formatter string is needed):

```
format(25, '010b')
```

but you ran into a simplification in Python 2.7, where you don't have to specify the positional parameter. The 2.6 equivalent is:

```
"{0:010b}".format(25)
```